# How to compile STM32f103 program on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, stm32, cross-compiling, cortex-m

I've some experience with programming stm32 arm cortex m3 micro controllers on Windows using Keil. I now want to move to linux environment and use open source tools to program STM32 cortex m3 devices.

I've researched a bit and found that I can use OpenOCD or Texane's ST Link to flash the chip. I also found out that I'll need a cross compiler to compile the code viz. gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain.

I want to know what basic source and header files are needed? Which are the core and systems file required to make a simple blink program.

I'm not intending to use HAL libraries as of now. I'm using stm32f103zet6 mcu (a very generic board). I went to http://regalis.com.pl/en/arm-cortex-stm32-gnulinux/ , but couldn't exactly pinpoint the files.

If there is any tutorial to start stm32 programming on linux environment, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: there are many examples that use a HAL and ones that are bare metal.  You can make your own headers, you dont need the stm hal nor cmsis, or if you want you can go get those and use whatever percentage you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example that is fairly portable across the stm32 family.  Doesnt do anything useful you have to fill in the blanks to blink an led or something (read the schematic, the manuals, enable the clocks to the gpio, follow the instructions to make it a push/pull output and so on, the set the bit or clear the bit, etc).

I have my reasons for how I do it others have theirs, and we all have various numbers of years or decades of experience behind those opinions. But at the end of they day they are opinions and many different solutions will work.

On the last so many releases of ubuntu you can simply do this to get a toolchain:

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Or you can go here and get a pre-built for your operating system

```
https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded
```

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
.align
.thumb_func
.globl PUT16
PUT16:
    strh r1,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
.end
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

sram.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0,stacktop
    mov sp,r0
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
.align
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.thumb_func
.globl PUT16
PUT16:
    strh r1,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
.end
```

sram.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

notmain.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );
#define STK_CSR 0xE000E010
#define STK_RVR 0xE000E014
#define STK_CVR 0xE000E018
#define STK_MASK 0x00FFFFFF
int delay ( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    while(n--)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            ra=GET32(STK_CSR);
            if(ra&(1<<16)) break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int rx;
    PUT32(STK_CSR,4);
    PUT32(STK_RVR,1000000-1);
    PUT32(STK_CVR,0x00000000);
    PUT32(STK_CSR,5);
    for(rx=0;;rx++)
    {
        dummy(rx);
        delay(50);
        dummy(rx);
        delay(50);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Makefile

```
#ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi
ARMGNU ?= arm-linux-gnueabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0


all : notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.bin notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.bin

clean:
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list
    rm -f *.bc
    rm -f *.opt.s
    rm -f *.norm.s
    rm -f *.hex

#---------------------------------

flash.o : flash.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) flash.s -o flash.o

sram.o : sram.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) sram.s -o sram.o

notmain.gcc.thumb.o : notmain.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.gcc.thumb.o

notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.bin : flash.ld flash.o notmain.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.elf -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.elf > notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.elf notmain.gcc.thumb.flash.bin -O binary

notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.bin : sram.ld sram.o notmain.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.elf -T sram.ld sram.o notmain.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.elf > notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.elf notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.hex -O ihex
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.elf notmain.gcc.thumb.sram.bin -O binary
```

You can also try/use this approach if you prefer.  I have my reasons not to, TL;DW.

```
void dummy ( unsigned int );
#define STK_MASK 0x00FFFFFF
#define STK_CSR (*((volatile unsigned int *)0xE000E010))
#define STK_RVR (*((volatile unsigned int *)0xE000E014))
#define STK_CVR (*((volatile unsigned int *)0xE000E018))
int delay ( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    while(n--)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            ra=STK_CSR;
            if(ra&(1<<16)) break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int rx;
    STK_CSR=4;
    STK_RVR=1000000-1;
    STK_CVR=0x00000000;
    STK_CSR=5;
    for(rx=0;;rx++)
    {
        dummy(rx);
        delay(50);
        dummy(rx);
        delay(50);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Between the arm docs which to some extent ST publishes a derivative for you (not everyone does that you should still go to arm).  Plus the st docs.

There is uart based bootloader built in (might be usb, etc), that is pretty easy to interface, lets see...my host code to download programs is in the hundreds of lines of code, probably took an evening or an afternoont to write. YMMV.  You can get if you dont already have, one of the discovery or nucleo boards, I recommend those anyway, you can use the debug end of it to program other stm32 or even other non st arm chips (not all, depends on what openocd supports, etc, but some) can get those for 30% cheaper than the dedicated stlink usb dongles and you dont need an extension usb cable, etc, etc. YMMV.  Can certainly use an stlink with openocd or texane stlink as you have already mentioned.

Due to the way the cortex-m boots I have provided two examples, one for burning to flash the other for downloading via openocd to ram and running that way, could arguably use the flash one too but you have to tweak the start address when you run.  I prefer this method. YMMV.

This approach you are portable and completely unencumbered by HAL limitations or requirements, build environments, etc.  But I recommend you try the various methods.  Bare metal like this the HAL types of bare metal with one or more st solutions and the cmsis approach.  Every year or so try again, see if the one you picked is still the one you like.

This example demonstrates though it does not take a whole lot.  I picked the cortex-m0 simply to avoid the armv7m thumb2 extensions.  thumb without those extensions is the most portable arm instruction set.  so again the code does mostly nothing, but does nothing on any stm32 cortex-m with a systick timer.

EDIT

This along with whatever you need to feed the linker would be the minimal non-C code.

```
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
```

And this is abbreviated depending on the chip vendor and core there can be dozens to hundreds of vectors for every little interrupt of every little thing.  The labels reset and hang in this case would be the names of C functions to handle those vectors (the documentation for the chip and core determine what vector handles what).  The first vector is always the initalization value of the stack pointer.  The second is always reset, the next few are common, after that they are generic interrupt pins on the core that the chip vendor wires up so you have to look at the chip vendor documentation.

The core design is such that registers are preserved for you so you dont need a little bit of assembly.  Going without any bootstrap then you assume to not have .bss zeroed nor .data initialized, and you cant return from the reset function, which in a real implementation you wouldnt but for demonstration tests, you might (blink an led 10 times then program is finished).

Your toolchain may have some other way to do this.  Since all toolchains should have an assembler and assemblers can generate tables of words, there is always that option, doesnt really make sense to create yet another tool and language for this but some folks feel the need.  Your toolchain may not require the entry point named _start and/or it may have a different entry point name requirement.

Even if you use Kiel, you should also try the gnu tools, easy(easier) to get, significantly more support and experience in the world than for Kiel.  May not produce as "good" of code as Kiel, performance wise or other, but should always have that in your back pocket as you will always be able to find help with gnu tools.

Comment: thanks for the reply dwelch! I see you are using assembly language here and I presume those are the thumb instructions. I'm totally naive to assembly programming on ARM. I want to program in C. On Keil, it used to include several files like core header files for cortex m3, system startup file (the only one written in assembly), device headers and few others. I want to be able to include and use those files and go on from there with a Makefile and cross compiler(bare metal). I hope I'm explaining myself clearly. Do ask me for any clarifications. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Yes, the cortex-m if you boot from flash, the only non-C thing you NEED, is a vector table (well and a linker script or commands of some sort).  In my flash code above the part with the .word stuff would be the minimum for this toolchain and use the volatile pointer stuff in the latter example.

Comment: The cortex-m's are thumb only machines, they do not support the fullsized arm instructions.  The  m0, m0+ are armv6-m and in addition to thumb have a small number of thumb2 extensions, the m3 and m4 and m7 have a large number of thumb2 extensions they support.  Thumb without thumb2 is the only instruction set that works across all the arm cores from the arm7tdmi to the present, and is the easier one to learn.

Answer (score 0):

http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/

There you'll find everything, including an IDE (Eclipse), toolchain, debugger, headers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I really appreciate it. However, I'm not looking for an IDE. In fact, I don't want to use an IDE. I just want to work with tool chain and Makefiles. Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question. I want to do everything from command line. I now wonder if its possible.?

Comment: You can create a sample project with eclipse and the plugins on the abovementioned site, then take the generated makefile and directory structure as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [package](http://www.openstm32.org/HomePage). This is IDE + toolchain + debugger and it available for linux platforms. You can research it and get any ideas to do what you want. I hope most of linux programs have commnad line interface.

In addition I can suggest to you: try to use LL api if it already available for your mcu.